# Do inferred mapping models always result in lightweight migrations?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

We've had a few cases of our App seemingly having trouble migrating user data when an *inferred* mapping model has been used. The App has needed too long to complete the migration and the migration has failed. Yes – we shouldn't be migrating during launch!

I'd like to know if it's possible that an inferred mapping model might *not* result in a lightweight migration. All the accounts I've read *suggest* that inferred mappings are necessarily lightweight, but I've not seen a strong statement that this is a guarantee.

The situation where we've had a problem included a property being deleted from the schema which was stored as external binary data (`Allows External Storage` was ticked in the schema editor). I wondered if this particular migration, with its model inferred automatically, might still require a heavy migration where the whole database is drawn in to memory.

Is there a way to tell if a specific inferred migration is heavy weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you yourself define a custom mapping model, the migration is *by definition* **lightweight**. This is the only possible interpretation of the definitions of "lightweight" and "custom" migration in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

This is independent from the migration failures you have seen. Maybe some changes *necessitate* a custom migration which is why the lightweight migration fails.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible for a specific migration to generally work fine using inferred mapping but fail for a few users because a manual migration is required for their specific data? What we observed was that for most users automatic (inferred) migration was fine, but for a few users it didn't complete within the time constraints of launching.

Comment: This sounds like expected behavior. It is not guaranteed that the migration is done within a certain time window. As you point out correctly, you need to give the user a UI so that the app can finish launching and complete the migration in the background. This would solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed, but it is implied that the "in situ" migration will be "quick" in some sense, it being just a database operation, even for fairly large DBs. I agree the doc equates "lightweight" with "inferred"; I'm still not convinced that it's absolutely saying that this means there will never be any further cost outside the DB. For example, it seems to me it would have needed to delete the external storage after migration. Perhaps deleting these files could have been time consuming.

Comment: I do not agree with your "quick migration" theory. The "in situ" assumption does not look plausible to me. Rather, the only affirmation you can make about lightweight migration is that it is not a custom migration. In view of this constructive discussion, you should at least up-vote this answer.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I've seen quite a bit of confirmation that in situ migrations can still take a while, as you state. Don't worry, I'm very likely to up vote your answer! I appreciate it and also the discussion!

Answer (score 0):

An inferred migration using `NSMigrationManager` is automatic, but it is *always* heavyweight. To get a lightweight migration you need to use `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` when adding the store to the coordinator.

The documentation kind of confuses this, but what I think it means to say is “if you are able to infer a mapping model, lightweight migration is possible *using the other API*.” So you can use this a test to check your assumptions, but the inferred model itself is not lightweight. You can also see from the `NSMigrationManager` API that it is not *in situ* because it wants separate source and destination URLs.